# User targeted apps store in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

My company has one SP 2013 intranet portal that is http://intranet.mycompany.com. Everyone in the company daily visits this site. On this portal i want some SharePoint-Hosted apps which user can use for his day to day work.

We have different departments like HR, Sales, Accounts, Production etc. I need apps store on this Portal where user can see apps from his department only, that means HR people should see only HR related apps likewise.